# How to validate an input text value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need my form to be submitted only if a user enters number 11 into a texbox.
If the box is empty or the input is other than 11, the form should not be submitted.
Here is how I try to achieve that:

```
    function validate(form_objmath) {
  if (test_required && !test_required(form_objmath)) {
    return false;
  }
  var obj3 = document.getElementById("Result");

  if (!obj3 || obj3.value != 11) {
    alert("The result is incorrect");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
```

For some reason, it gives me "The result is incorrect" even when I enter 11 into the textbox and the form doesn't get submitted.

Please advise.
Thank you!

Comment: There's actually nothing wrong with your code.  Are you injecting a valid form object into the parameter of the function?

Comment: I don't really know. I'm very new at JavaScript.
My task is to add this piece of validation to an existing code.
I took the below function that checks two email fields and I used it as a sample for my function.
The below is the first function I used as a sample:
function validate(form_obj) { if (test_required && !test_required(form_obj)) { return false; } var obj1 = document.getElementById("Email"); var obj2 = document.getElementById("email2"); if (!obj1 || !obj2 || obj1.value != obj2.value) { alert("Email address fields do not match"); return false; } return true; }

Answer (score 3):

Use the `&&` instead of `||`

`if (obj3 && parseInt(obj3.value) === 11) {
    return true;
}
alert("The result is incorrect");
return false;`

If obj3 is defined AND it equals 11, submit form.

Use `===` [MDN source on operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vk4E8/)

Comment: +1 because you're the only one who managed to not convert 11 into a string for comparison. However, you should `parseInt` the `obj3.value` so you don't get a `NaN` result.

Comment: How do I do that?
I just put in if (!obj3 && obj3.value !== 11) and input 12 into the textbox, and the form got submitted instead of giving me the error message.

Comment: Oops! it needs to be `===` 11. Fixing error now. I'm sorry! Then adjust your logic to submit within the if clause

Comment: Robb,
Now it looks like this:
if (!obj3 && obj3.value !=== 11)
And it submits even when the field is empty.

Comment: I'm sorry I have my logic backwards, fixing my answer now

Comment: Robb, I'm so sorry to bother you, but have you had a chance to fix your answer?
Thank you!
Vita

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. Check my answer, does that help?

Comment: Robb, thank you!
But now it gives the error message in all three cases, even when 11 is the input.

Comment: Added a fiddle showing that when `obj3.value` is 11, it returns true, otherwise false. Not sure what else to tell you. I'd have to see all of your code. Notice I changed where the return statements are.